# Separate Email addresses in different column by their domain name

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I have a list (Column) of Email addresses (@Gmail.com, @Hotmail.com, @live.com etc) and some other companies domain addresses.

I need to separate  @Gmail.com, @Hotmail.com, @live.com  address from others and write them in next column.

I know by using conditional formatting I can highlight and copy/paste them in separate column but I really don't know where to start or how to do the same using Excel-VBA.

**For Example:**

[image]

**Update:**
*For full information please follow - https://youtu.be/zjF7oLLgtms*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your emails are in column A, and you want them to go to B:

```
Sub splitmail2()
Dim lrow As Long
lrow = Sheets("sheet1").Cells(Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("sheet1").Range("A:A").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="*" & "hotmail" & "*", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="*" & "gmail" & "*", Operator:=xlOr
Sheets("sheet1").Range("A2:A" & lrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
Range("B2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("A2:A" & lrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).ClearContents
Sheets("sheet1").AutoFilterMode = False
End Sub
```

As per your comment, if you want to put the results on the same line as they came from, the below loop will do the trick. However it is significantly slower than the previous method if used on large datasets.

```vb
Sub splitmail3()
Dim lrow As Long
Dim cel As Range
lrow = Sheets("sheet1").Cells(Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For Each cel In Range("A2:A" & lrow)
If InStr(UCase(cel.Value), "HOTMAIL") Or InStr(UCase(cel.Value), "GMAIL") Then
Range("B" & cel.Row).Value = cel.Value
cel.ClearContents
Else
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: your method did not shift emails into next subsequent cell rather making a list without blank cells. I updated picture to elaborate more. please help

Comment: This can be done with a `foreach` loop, but it will be significantly slower. I'll see if I have time later to update my answer and give you the option to do it as expected.

Comment: @IbneAshiq There you go, let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need VBA for this:

- Write the domains (without '@') that you want to separate in a NAMED Range [Domain_List]
- Assuming your list to separate is in column A

Formula for column B is:

```
=IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RIGHT($A1,LEN($A1)-FIND("@",$A1)),Domain_List,1),"")<>"",$A1,"")
```

Formula for column C is:

```
=IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RIGHT($A1,LEN($A1)-FIND("@",$A1)),Domain_List,1),"")<>"","",$A1)
```